# Making a vertical List of Radio Buttons for a list of strings in struts 2?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm using a struts radio tag that is being populated with a list of strings:

View that I am using is :-

```
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
    <s:iterator value="importFiles"> 
    <s:radio name="mifFile" label="Mif File" theme="simple"/>
    <s:property/><br>
    </s:iterator>                               
</td>
</tr>
```

Above, I have a list of strings named importFiles. While using this, I am getting an error "List attribute necessary in Radio Tag". But I don't know for a simple List of strings what should i put in List attribute.

It is similar to previous posts but for doing vertical show of radio buttons, they have taken a example of List having 2 fields.

In this case, how will it be achieved? Please help me out in this regard.....

Comment: Post the generated HTML. You probably can achieve that with CSS only, with no need to roll up your own theme for custom markup generation...

Answer (score 4):

Try using this

```
 <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <s:iterator value="importFiles" status="importFilesCount">
        <input type="radio" name="mifFile" value="<s:property />"><s:property /><br>
        </s:iterator>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

It will arrange your radiolist vertically.

Comment: it will print the radios in horizontal direction....and i want them in vertical direction. Thats the problem...

Comment: Alright, I have edited it and it works fine as per your requirement. Give it a try again

Answer (score 4):

You can put single values to `list` attribute in `<s:radio>` tag also. Use the `top` keyword to get current element.

```
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
  <s:iterator value="importFiles"> 
    <s:radio list="top" name="mifFile" label="Mif File" theme="simple"/><br/>
  </s:iterator>                               
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @ShubhamJain: Good. If this answer helped you accept/upvote it.