# Java MultiThreading Interview - restricting access to a method upto a certain limit at any time

Tags: java, multithreading

I got this question asked in an interview. I had to create a utility function which cannot be accessed by more than n number of a thread at any point of time. So,if (n+1)th thread requests then it should wait until any of the previous thread completes.

Here is what i offered as a solution :

```
 class MyMathUtil implements Runnable {
double a;
double b;
String name="demo";
Thread t;
static int currentCount=0;
static int maxCount=2;

MyMathUtil(double v1,double v2) {
        a = v1;
        b = v2;
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
        t.start();
    }
 public void InternalPow(double a,double b){
     System.out.println("Power of "+a+" and "+b+" : "+Math.pow(a, b));
 }

    public void run() {
        try {
            if(currentCount<maxCount){
                currentCount++;
                InternalPow(a,b);
                notify();
            }else{
                synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
                    Thread.currentThread().wait();; 
                }
            }


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(name + "Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
    }
}

class TestMyMathUtil {
public static void main(String args[]) {
     new MyMathUtil(10.2,8);
     new MyMathUtil(11,56);
     new MyMathUtil(10.2,9);
     }
}
```

But the third request(which is the (n+1)th request) doesn't gets executed ever.Can anyone explain why? An even better solution would also be appreciated.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: One of the possible solutions: [Making a vertical List of Radio Buttons for a list of strings in struts 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17850320/1700321).

Comment: @DaveNewton.. theme="simple"

Comment: @AleksandrM.. i need the same thing for a static list...as u can see i have already used a <br> tag at the end like it is being shown in the link you provided..but still it didn't work!

Comment: @Aquarius You can use same *static* list in the iterator tag.